# Validação de campos dos formulários Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou usando o MVC5 Razor para criar meus formulários, 
agora estou com uma dúvida para as validações dos campos
desse formulário;

Exemplo:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nome, "Nome:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Nome, "Nenhum" , new { @class = "form-dropdown" } )

    @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.IsObrigaInfoCidade, new { @class = "form-checkbox" });
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsObrigaInfoCidade, "Obrigar Informar a Cidade")

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cidade, "Cidade")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Cidade, "Nenhum" , new { @class = "form-dropdown" } )
```

Validações:

```
- Quando m => m.ID for igual a 0(zero), então o enabled = true, caso contratio enabled = false;
- Quando o chequebox IsObrigaInfoCidade estiver selecionado o campo CIDADE deve ficar disabed = false,
caso contrário a cidade deve ficar enabled = true;
```

Acredito que tenho q fazer a validação de campo pro campo com Javascript e Jquery, porém não sei como fazer
ou se é a melhor forma para isso? e se o usuário desabilitar o javascript da página? Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Depende, você já tem o "m.ID" no renderizar da página ou ele é um valor alterado pela tela/preenchido pelo usuário?

Comment: Ja tenho o valor do ID, mas o IsObrigaInfoCidade vai ser alterado na tela!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dito na sua pergunta, se você já tem o valor do ID, basta fazer uma comparação no próprio Razor para decidir como o campo será exibido:

```
@if (Model.ID == 0)
{ 
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nome, "Nome:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Nome, "Nenhum" , new { @class = "form-dropdown" } )

    @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.IsObrigaInfoCidade, new { @class = "form-checkbox" });
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsObrigaInfoCidade, "Obrigar Informar a Cidade")

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cidade, "Cidade")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Cidade, "Nenhum" , new { @class = "form-dropdown" } )
}
else
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nome, "Nome:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Nome, "Nenhum" , new { @class = "form-dropdown", @disabled = "disabled" } )

    @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.IsObrigaInfoCidade, new { @class = "form-checkbox", @disabled = "disabled" });
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsObrigaInfoCidade, "Obrigar Informar a Cidade")

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cidade, "Cidade")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Cidade, "Nenhum" , new { @class = "form-dropdown", @disabled = "disabled" } )
}
```

Já para a condição do checkbox, você precisa fazer no seu JS:

```
 $('#IsObrigaInfoCidade').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#Cidade').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#Cidade').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
 });
```

Comment: O @IF funcionou bem, mas ainda esta dando problema quando ao clicar no checkbox: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Pelo jeito seu jquery não está instanciado na página.. verifique isto

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia.

Você realmente pode fazer via Javascript e Jquery, o usuário pode sim desabilitar o java script, nesse cenário, acredito que você esteja usando alguma classe de modelo no seu MVC, a melhor forma é usar os dataannotations diretamente na classe em questão: veja um exemplo: acima de cada propriedade da classe está as anotações sobre a propriedade e uma delas é informada que a informação é requerida [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo Nome")] para isso use os namespaces System.componentModel e System.componentModel.DataAnnotations.

Dessa forma mesmo que o usuário desativar o Javascript, quando a requisição chegar no servidor as informações não serão validadas.

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Projeto.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClienteId { get; set; } //ID da tabela

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo Nome")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 150 caracteres")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minimo de 2 caracteres")]
    public string Nome { get; set; } // Nome do cliente

    using System.Collections.Generic;
```

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ProjetoModeloDDD.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo Nome")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 150 caracteres")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minimo de 2 caracteres")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo Sobrenome")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 150 caracteres")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minimo de 2 caracteres")]
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo Email")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 150 caracteres")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Preencha um e-mail válido")]
    [DisplayName("E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

    public bool ClienteEspecial(Cliente cliente)
    {
        return cliente.Ativo && DateTime.Now.Year - cliente.DataCadastro.Year >= 5;
    }
}
```

}[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo Sobrenome")]
        [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 150 caracteres")]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minimo de 2 caracteres")]
        public string Sobrenome { get; set; } //Sobrenome do cliente

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo Email")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 150 caracteres")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Preencha um e-mail válido")]
    [DisplayName("E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; } //Email do cliente

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; } // Checa se o cliente está ativo

    public virtual IEnumerable<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

}
```

}